# behavior of len() with arange()

Tags: python, pandas

With this dataframe, dff:

```
   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  b
4  4  b
5  5  b
6  6  c
7  7  c
```

I understand how `len(dff) == 8`

However, I don't understand the answer from:

```
dff['counts'] = np.arange(len(dff))
```

which is

```
     A  B  counts  
  0  0  a       0  
  1  1  a       1  
  2  2  b       2  
  3  3  b       3  
  4  4  b       4  
  5  5  b       5  
  6  6  c       6  
  7  7  c       7
```

Shouldn't `dff['counts']` be 8 for every row? What is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what [`np.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) does:

```
In [32]:

np.arange(8) 
Out[32]:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Here the length of your df is being used to set the `stop` param:

From the docs:

```
numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)
Return evenly spaced values within a given interval.

Values are generated within the half-open interval [start, stop) (in other words, the interval including start but excluding stop). For integer arguments the function is equivalent to the Python built-in range function, but returns an ndarray rather than a list.

When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

Parameters: 
start : number, optional
Start of interval. The interval includes this value. The default start value is 0.
stop : number
End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.
step : number, optional
Spacing between values. For any output out, this is the distance between two adjacent values, out[i+1] - out[i]. The default step size is 1. If step is specified, start must also be given.
dtype : dtype
The type of the output array. If dtype is not given, infer the data type from the other input arguments.
Returns:    
arange : ndarray
Array of evenly spaced values.
For floating point arguments, the length of the result is ceil((stop - start)/step). Because of floating point overflow, this rule may result in the last element of out being greater than stop.
```

if you wanted to set every row to the same value you could do just

```
In [34]:

dff['counts'] = len(dff)
dff
Out[34]:
   A  B  counts
0  0  a       8
1  1  a       8
2  2  b       8
3  3  b       8
4  4  b       8
5  5  b       8
6  6  c       8
7  7  c       8
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i think i'm not used to the fact of the merging of a dataframe and list automatically if they are the same length

Comment: Pandas will either set all rows to the same value if you pass a scalar, will align your array like object if they are the same length, or align along indices/columns if it's a Series/DataFrame this is expected behaviour, for instance you'd get an error if you tried `dff['counts'] = np.arange(7)`

Comment: could you give a quick example of "align along indices/columns if its a Series/DataFrame"?

Comment: basically if did the following you will see what I mean dff['c'] = pd.Series(np.arange(8), index=np.arange(3,11))` you will see that because the other Series index starts at 3, the values from that index value are assigned and the first 3 rows end up as `NaN`